# Structuring for an informal interview

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process

**Scenario:** you've interviewed several candidates, narrowed down all proficiency-related concerns, done the main interview, and have a final shortlist. You want to find out which of the candidates are likely to get on best with their team mates, and you've arranged to meet the final candidates (separately) in a cafe over the weekend for a casual final interview, possibly with a very loose structure or set of questions that can help to gauge personality.

**Main goals:**

- Make sure the candidate is at ease and able to chat
- Avoid the candidate feeling under pressure, which can happen in a standard interview scenario.
- Somehow come up with a way to measure the candidates against each other nonsubjectively.

**Question:** How can an interview like this be structured? Is it even possible?

Comment: I've made  an edit that hopefully may make it clearer. Essentially looking for a nonsubjective personality gauge method... I'm not sure if there is such a thing either :/

Comment: *You want to find out which of the candidates are likely to get on best with their team mates*. I can't imagine any objective measure when that is your desired outcome.

Comment: Wouldn't a sequence of lunches be a better option here rather than trying to take a weekend afternoon to order the short list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you plan on working with each other in a café under informal circumstances, you need more ways and settings to evaluate your candidates on how well they'll get along with teammates.

Some people are the life of the party and get along with everyone until you ask them to explain a suggestion or worse yet, try to question any of their actions. Try and structure a meeting and possibly simulate a client meeting (that could happen in a café). This could involve making a short presentation, fielding questions or gathering requirements.

I would use the casual café or lunch interview as just one final check only for candidate(s) I was going to make an offer. Make sure everyone can sit down, relax, drink a beverage and have something to eat if available. Don't expect them to carry the entire conversation unless that is a part of the job requirement. It's not the time to ask them a hundred personal questions either. That's too much like an interview. The key should be on conversation and natural interactions and just make sure they don't do something very inappropriate.

At the end, I think your team just needs to vote "yes" or "no" and you can decide what score is required.